# List all files with specific extension beneath a directory in Scala

Tags: scala, file, recursion, directory, subdirectory

I am trying to get a List of all files with a given extension from within a given directory (and it's sub-directories).
So far what I have done :

```
var pipelineList: List[File] = Nil

  private def getPipelines(dir: File): Unit =
    {
      val tmp = dir.listFiles();
      for (f <- tmp) {
        if (f.isDirectory())
          getPipelines(f)
        else if (f.isFile() && (f.getName.endsWith(".pipeline"))) {
          pipelineList = pipelineList ::: List(f)
        }
      }
    }
```

This is working as I'm getting all fies with ".pipeline" extension but I want the function to return a list of File objects (List,Array anything) instead of modifying an outside list. I tried declaring the list inside but the recursive calls re-initialize the list everytime, also tried passing the result list as a parameter but Scala throws error when I try to add anything to it saying it cannot re-assign to val.

Also tried another way :

```
def getListOfFiles(dir: File): Array[File] = {
    val filesList= dir.listFiles
    filesList ++ filesList.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(getListOfFiles)
    filesList.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".pipeline"))
}
```

This is successfully getting all the files beneath the directory but the filter is not working as it's not returning anything even though the predicate gets satisfied.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
filesList ++ filesList.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(getListOfFiles)
```

is returning a new **Immutable Array** without changing the `filesList`. so you need to:

```
val res = filesList ++ filesList.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(getListOfFiles)
res.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".pipeline"))
```

Comment: Awesome!
Thanks.That worked.

I'm new to Scala so please forgive my ignorance,
`filesList ++ filesList.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(getListOfFiles)`
is returning a new Immutable Array but the filter function returns a new collection with the elements matching the predicate. It does not try to modify the Immutable Array. right?